# Is Aoi Koga (Kaguya-sama's VA) in the Kaguya-sama 2021 live-action movie?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

In the *Kaguya-sama* 2021 live-action movie around 1:21:47 timestamp, there is a following scene.

[image]

I know Aoi Koga is in the 2019 live-action movie, but is that also Aoi in the 2021 live-action movie?

See below for the 2019 live-action movie:

1. Kaguya (live actor) gives the pre-ordered ticket to the Kaguya (VA):

   [image]
2. Kaguya (VA) asks Kaguya (live actor) to choose a seat:

   [image]